# Changing the size of the background of a link

Tags: html, css

I want to know how I can change the background size around a link.

here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Library for Macintosh games.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>Old Mac Games for Free</h1>
<p><a href="google.com" id="link">Google</a></p>
<script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</canvas>
</body> 
</html>
```

here is my CSS

html {background-color: #d0e0c9}

```
h1 {
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 85px;
margin-top: 85px;
font-size: 45px;
}

#link {
background-color:  fuchsia;
text-align: center;
margin:500;
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean, background size? an element's background is always as big as the element itself.

Comment: I think I've correctly assumed what you're looking for. Please comment and let me know if I've correctly guessed what you mean by "background-size"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're referring to the padding of the link element.
If you'd like to increase the appearance of the background of the link element, you can easily add in this css:

```
#link {
background-color:  fuchsia;
text-align: center;
padding:2em;
}
```

You should be able to  see the link's "background-size" easily.

You can see a working demonstration here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOVYvL

I invite you to check out some further reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the size of the link's text, you can use

```
<span style="font-size: 10px;"> <a href"..."> Text Here </a></span>
```

If you want to change the font color, "color: blue;", if you want to change the background color "behind the text":

```
<div style="background-color: black;">
<span style="font-size: 10px;">
<a href"..."> 
Text Here 
</a>
</span>
</div>
```

And you change the size of the div like this:

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 5px">
<div style="width: 50%; height: 5px; margin: auto;">
```

Here is a link to common CSS styling: http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

EDIT: Also, its pretty unclear what you mean by "background size" you might want to be a little more specific when you post a question!